# How to getting a selected object from DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I'm looking for something like this :

```
public static Object GetCellRowValue(DataGridView gridView, String columnName)
{
    Object o = gridView.CurrentRow.Cells[columnName].Value;

    return o != null ? o.ToString() : null;
}

public static T GetRow(DataGridView gridView)
{
    T linha = (dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as T);
    return linha;

}
```

I would like to make something this way with but with the GridControl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are built-in methods to get the selected values:

```
object selectedCellValue = gridView1.FocusedValue;

object columnOfSelectedRow = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("ColumnName");

T selectedObject = gridView1.GetFocusedRow() as T;
```

See [Get Cell Values](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument753/obtain) for more details.